# Are there any low temperature (60 - 100 degree celsius) soldering pastes?

Tags: conductivity

I'm looking for  low temperature soldering paste that doesn't come in a wheel of filament. It seems tin and bismuth soldering pastes have a melting point of around 160 degrees Celsius.

Are there any formulations, or products on the market, for an even lower temperature soldering paste? I guess [this company](https://www.indium.com/solder-alloy-guide/results.php) makes them, but I'm wondering if there is a formulation with a stronger market presence.

I need a conductivity strong enough to use ICs.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Building a makeshift reflow oven and pick-and-place machine for prototyping inside a cardboard box. Some materials used in creating it have a plastic deformation temperature around 105 degrees celsius

Comment: never thought id read that sentence ^^ lol

Comment: It's the age of plastics, yo!! -- mick jagger

Comment: Oh man, I just do not think that is going to work on multiple levels. Why can you not just a soldering iron or dedicated  toaster oven?

Comment: You want to reflow solder in a cardboard box? For fun? I can’t imagine why? :)

Comment: Guys, this is fairly common in 3d printing circles, to have a cardboard box hold an ambient temperature of around 60 degrees Celsius for helping with bed adhesion for certain plastics.

Comment: Even if the plastic won't deform until 105 degrees, repeatedly heating it to 100 degrees will eventually degrade the plastic. You also need to think that some IC's use pads for heat transfer which can go well over 100 degrees, do you want your solder paste to melt again when you use your board?

Comment: but we are not talking about plastics...we are talking about metals. what does something being common in 3D printing have to do with soldering?

Comment: Can we stick to the question at hand? These are engineering problems I have considered already (except the heatpad point - but it doesn't apply here)

Comment: There isn't any solder paste that melts that low. The lowest that I've ever found melts around 118°C. That is called "Indium" solder and it comes on a wire spool. Pastes are higher.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Indium has some other products that melt at 60 degrees. But it seems you have to go through a tech support engineer to purchase them. I will look into Indium solder

Comment: Indium is exactly the company I was going to go check. 60  C solder is a niche product, so you shouldn't be surprised if a niche company makes it. FWIW, they've been around for at least 20 years, so as far as market presence goes, they're probably as good as you're going to get for this kind of product.

Comment: OK, actually the company has existed since 1934...that's some market presence.

Comment: My reflow skillet cost me $5 at Goodwill, plus a thermocouple temperature meter for $20 from Fleabay.  Add a scrounged plate of glass for a lid (you could use tinfoil and live with not seeing the process).  It works great for a total dollar investment of $25.  As a bonus, my shop smelled like frying bacon every time I used it for the first dozen times or so.  Why compromise your soldering job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are chip removal alloys (lead-free) that melt around 79-91°C.

As well as being expensive, they're probably brittle and perhaps [nasty in other ways](https://www.chipquik.com/msds/SMD1NL.pdf).

Leaded alloys are available that melt at ~58°C, a bit less than what you are asking for.

As far as I know, those alloys are not available in paste form, however. What the industry calls "[Low Temperature Soldering](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/presentation/low-temperature-soldering-introduction.pdf)" is more like peak 190°C (lead-free process).